# Is it possible to access a textbox entry from one class (and append to it) from another class? In this case, it would be from Page2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I cannot find a way to access this textbox and append to it from another class using Tkinter.

I can't use the method I've used before (by calling other entries `StringVar()`), which has lead to a halt in my programming. As textbox cannot be named a `StringVar()`, I am confused as to how I could go about doing this.

```
import tkinter as tk

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("1350x750")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(row=0, column=0)

        container.config(bg="gray20")

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (ReservationPage, ReceiptPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.show_frame(ReservationPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class ReservationPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.MainFrame = tk.Frame(self, width=1350, height=700, bg="gray20")
        self.MainFrame.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.MoorFrame = tk.LabelFrame(self, bg="gray20", width=300, height=150)
        self.MoorFrame.place(x=450, y=120)

        ReceiptPageButton1 = tk.Button(self, text="Receipts", font=("Helvetica", 20, "bold"),bg="gray20", fg="light grey",
                                       bd=0,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ReceiptPage))
        ReceiptPageButton1.place(x=100, y=30)


class ReceiptPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.MainFrame = tk.Frame(self, width=1350, height=700, bg="gray20")
        self.MainFrame.grid(row=0,column=0)

        ReservationPageButton1 = tk.Button(self, text="Reservations", font=("Helvetica", 20, "bold"),bg="gray20", fg="light grey",
                                       bd=0,command=lambda: controller.show_frame(ReservationPage))
        ReservationPageButton1.place(x=80, y=30)

        ReceiptBox = tk.Text(self, height=20, width=137, font=("Helvetica",11,"bold"))
        ReceiptBox.place(x=27, y=165)
```

Comment: Yes, if you make the Textbox an instance variable, you can access it from another from with `self.master.frames[Page1].textbox`. You need to show a [mcve] if you want an example of that.

Comment: Also, your `controller` Frame and `MainFrame` Frame seem pretty useless. Why do you have those?

Comment: @Novel, I have updated my post. Apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Novel: the controller and `MainFrame` are there because he copied and pasted this code from an online tutorial. That tutorial stole code from an early version of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a controller, which is designed to be a conduit between the pages. You need to update it to have a function that returns the page you want, and from there you can access any of the attributes of that page.

First, add the following definition to `MainWindow`:

```
def get_page(self, page_class):
    return self.frames[page_class]
```

Next, save the `Text` widget to an instance variable:

```
class ReceiptPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        self.ReceiptBox = tk.Text(self, ...)
        ...
```

With that, you can access `ReceiptBox` from any other page like this:

```
receipt_page = self.controller.get_page(ReceiptPage)
receipt_page.delete("1.0", "end")
```

In your case you probably want to tie your button to a function that writes the receipt and then switches to it.

```
class ReservationPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        ReceiptPageButton1 = tk.Button(..., command=self.generate_receipt)
        ...

    def generate_receipt(self):
        receipt_page = self.controller.get_page(ReceiptPage)
        receipt_page.ReceiptBox.delete("1.0", "end")
        receipt_page.ReceiptBox.insert("end", "Here is your receipt...")
        self.controller.show_frame(ReceiptPage)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example. Note I also removed a lot of other useless code. The one thing I didn't do that I recommend you do is stop using `place()`. Learn to use `grid()` and `pack()` instead. It's a little harder to learn but once you know how they work it's much MUCH easier to program because tkinter will figure out all those pixel locations for you.

```
import tkinter as tk

bg_color = "gray20"
button_style = dict(
    font=("Helvetica", 20, "bold"),
    bg=bg_color,
    fg="light grey",
    bd=0)

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.geometry("1350x750")

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (ReservationPage, ReceiptPage):
            frame = F(self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.show_frame(ReservationPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class ReservationPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, bg=bg_color, **kwargs)
        self.MoorFrame = tk.LabelFrame(self, bg=bg_color, width=300, height=150)
        self.MoorFrame.place(x=450, y=120)

        ReceiptPageButton1 = tk.Button(self, text="Receipts", command=lambda: parent.show_frame(ReceiptPage), **button_style)
        ReceiptPageButton1.place(x=100, y=30)

        test_button = tk.Button(self, text="Test add text", command=self.add, **button_style)
        test_button.place(x=100, y=100)

    def add(self):
        textbox = self.master.frames[ReceiptPage].ReceiptBox
        textbox.insert(tk.END, "This is only a test\n")

class ReceiptPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, bg=bg_color, **kwargs)

        ReservationPageButton1 = tk.Button(self, text="Reservations", command=lambda: parent.show_frame(ReservationPage), **button_style)
        ReservationPageButton1.place(x=80, y=30)

        # using a name that starts with "self." makes this an instance variable
        self.ReceiptBox = tk.Text(self, height=20, width=137, font=("Helvetica",11,"bold"))
        self.ReceiptBox.place(x=27, y=165)

def main():
    root = MainWindow()
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Your `add` function is missing a step. OP's code would raise the receipt window to the front when the button was clicked.